# jQuery / jQuery UI slider event for jump/click. Function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am creating a jQuery slider to loop through a collection of divs, if I hold the slider down and drag it and let go. The `handleSlider()` is called. If I click on a random point in the slider, the function never gets called. I've tried to use two other event types with no luck. Is there an event handler for "When the user clicks/jumps" on the slider without sliding?

```
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handleSlider();
        }
    });
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({ stop: function( event, ui ) {handleSlider();}});
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({ change: function( event, ui ) {handleSlider();}});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure change should work here (http://jsfiddle.net/zAzvL/). Is that not the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Much better but not perfect, I took out the functions. I think I have a function firing off before the slider has completed it's update.

Comment: `slide` fires every single time the mouse moves while sliding. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the syntax. Every time you use $ it makes a new jQuery object, so

```
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handleSlider();
        }
    });
//below are not necessarily referring to the original slider, but rather creating new sliders.
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({ stop: function( event, ui ) {handleSlider();}});
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({ change: function( event, ui ) {handleSlider();}});
```

@Andrew is correct in his syntax. All you should need is the 'change' event, which you can set in your original declaration like this:

```
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
         handleSlider();
    }
});
```

or even like this:

```
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({
    change: handleSlider
});
```

if you need to attach an event handler after the fact, do so like this:

```
$( "#video_seek" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
     handleSlider();
});
```

or even:

```
$( "#video_seek" ).bind( "slidechange", handleSlider);
```

(Edit)

Putting it all together and avoiding the production of subsequent jQuery objects.

```
var videoSeek = $('#video_seek');
videoSeek.slider({
     slide: handleSlider
});
//added later on not necessary just for example of doing so
videoSeek.bind('slidechange', handleSlider);

function handleSlider(event, ui){
     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Been great help. I didn't realise that it created the object every time, I treated it more as a selector!

Comment: Here is one additional tip that really helps with program memory. If you are going to select the same thing more than once you, save your jquery object in a javascript var, like this:   var elem = $('#elem'); Then elem.css('background','red'); elem.hide(); or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the events inside the actual object creation or bind them afterwards...

```
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {handleSlider();}
    stop: function(event, ui) {handleSlider();}
    change: function( event, ui ) {handleSlider();}
});
```

or:

```
$( "#video_seek" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    step: 1,
});

$( "#video_seek" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
    handleSlider();
});
```